# how to receive objects by condition in connecting table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have table `Games` and `Badges` they are connecting by table `BadgesGames`.

```
t.integer "badge_id"
t.integer "game_id"
t.boolean "shown",    default: false
```

I have `Game` object and i want find all `Badges` which wans't `shown`

```
game_object.(condition?).badges
```

How to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` 'through' relationship set up:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_badges
  has_many :badges, through: :game_badges
end

class GameBadge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :badge
end

class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_badges
  has_many :games, through: :game_badges
end
```

Then you can use the following:

```
game.game_badges.where(shown: false).map(&:badge)
```

Comment: I think you'll need to use `.map(&:badge)` instead of `.badges` as the `where` method is going to return a collection of `game_badges` which won't know what `badges` means.