# Any element true in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a relation of `organizations` and `advisors` through `organization_advisors`. `organization_advisors` has a field that is `is_verified`. I want to find any `advisors` for a particular `organization` that have `is_verified` as false. Something like this (which doesn't work)

```
<% unless @organization.advisors.is_verified.any? %>
    Approve Advisors
<% end %>
```

I've also tried:

```
<% unless @organization.organization_advisors.is_verified.any? %>
    Approve Advisors
<% end %>
```

I need to know if any advisors of `@organization` are not `is_verified`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `is_verified` is in `organization_advisers` it is enough to check if any of them exist:

```
<% unless @organization.organization_advisors.where(is_verified: false).any? %>
  Approve Advisors
<% end %>
```

I assume that you have the following structure:

```
class Organization
  has_many :organization_advisors
  has_many :advisors, through: :organization_advisors
end

class OrganizationAdvisor
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :advisor
end

class Advisor
  has_many :organization_advisors
  has_many :organizations, through: :organization_advisors
end
```

See also similar question here: [how to receive objects by condition in connecting table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540261/how-to-receive-objects-by-condition-in-connecting-table).

Comment: I took bumpy's and came up with yours. Yours is correct and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland My answer is different from bumpy's because his code assumes `is_verified` field on the wrong model, so I proposed correct solution and clarified database structure.

Comment: You are correct. I don't know Rails, so should have stuck to my knitting. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<% unless @organization.advisors.where(is_verified: false).any? %>
    Approve Advisors
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bumpy. I needed to change `@organization.advisors` to `@organization.organization_advisors` because that is the table with the `is_verified` on it. Thanks a ton.